Box2D: Projected Trajectory of a ball
I am trying to make a basketball shoot game. My issue is with my projected trajectory line. It seems to be pretty accurate when the initial velocity isn't above ~140. I have tried adjusting my formula a ton, I mostly just followed this tutorial:
https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/projected-trajectory
Here is the code; I am not sure if something is wrong with my formula or there is something I am missing in regards to Box2D within Flutter Flame (what I'm using to develop this)
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bball_blast/Background.dart';
import 'package:bball_blast/entities/Hoop.dart';
import 'package:bball_blast/entities/Wall.dart';
import 'package:bball_blast/entities/ball.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:flame/extensions.dart';
import 'package:flame_forge2d/flame_forge2d.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bball_blast/config.dart';

class BBallBlast extends Forge2DGame with PanDetector, HasGameRef<BBallBlast>{

  BBallBlast(): super(
      gravity: Vector2(0,gravity),
      camera: CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(width: gameWidth, height: gameHeight),
    );

  //vars we need to be visible thoughout entire file
  late Ball ball; 
  double linearImpulseStrengthMult = 12.5;
  late Vector2 impulse;

  //positional vars
  double startPosX = 00;
  double startPosY = 00;
  late Vector2 startPos;

  //Vars for determining how ball should be thrown
  late Offset startOfDrag;
  late Offset currentDragPos;
  late Offset dragBehindBall = Offset.zero;
  bool isDragging = false;

  bool isShot = false;

  @override
  FutureOr<void> onLoad() async {
    //set startPos of ball
    startPos = Vector2(startPosX, startPosY);

    //load images into cache
    await images.loadAllImages();

    //make ballSprite and ball
    Sprite ballImg = await loadSprite('ball.png');
    ball = Ball(this, Vector2(startPosX, startPosY), ballImg);

    //add leftWall and rightWall, and ceiling
    Wall wallLeft = Wall(Vector2(camera.visibleWorldRect.topLeft.dx-1, camera.visibleWorldRect.topLeft.dy), 1.0, gameHeight);
    Wall wallRight = Wall(Vector2(camera.visibleWorldRect.topRight.dx+1, camera.visibleWorldRect.topRight.dy), 1.0, gameHeight);
    Wall ceiling = Wall(Vector2(camera.visibleWorldRect.topLeft.dx-1, camera.visibleWorldRect.topRight.dy-1), gameWidth, 1.0);

    //create hoopimg, hoop, and add it
    Sprite hoopImg = await loadSprite('hoop.png');
    Hoop hoop = Hoop(this, true, hoopImg);

    //add components to game  
    world.addAll([Background(), ball, wallLeft, wallRight, ceiling, hoop]);

    debugMode=true;

    super.onLoad();
  }


  //-----------------------INPUT HANDLING (DRAGS)-----------------------
  @override
  void onPanStart(DragStartInfo info) {
    //when user drags screen, store whre it happened and let program know dragging=true
    startOfDrag = Offset(info.eventPosition.global.x, info.eventPosition.global.y);
    isDragging = true;
    isShot = false;
  }

  @override 
  void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateInfo info) {
    //we get the dragPos, then we get the distance of the drag relative to starting point 
    //then apply it to our "dragBehindBall" which is given to trajectory drawing 
    currentDragPos = Offset(info.eventPosition.global.x, info.eventPosition.global.y);
    double relX = startOfDrag.dx - currentDragPos.dx;
    double relY = startOfDrag.dy - currentDragPos.dy;
    dragBehindBall = Offset((relX), (relY));
  }

  @override
  void onPanEnd(DragEndInfo info) {
    //make ball move when thrown
    ball.body.setType(BodyType.dynamic);
    impulse = Vector2(dragBehindBall.dx, dragBehindBall.dy) * linearImpulseStrengthMult;
    ball.body.applyLinearImpulse(impulse);
    print("SHOT STRENGTH: ${Vector2(dragBehindBall.dx, dragBehindBall.dy) * linearImpulseStrengthMult}");
    print("VEL: ${ball.body.linearVelocity}");
    print("BALL MASS: ${ball.body.mass}");
    //reset necessary vars 
    isDragging=false;
    isShot = true;
    dragBehindBall = Offset(startPosX, startPosY);
  }

  int count = 1;
  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
      //print("TIMESTEP: $count VEL: ${ball.body.linearVelocity} \n POS: ${ball.getSuperPosition()}");
  }

  
} 

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:bball_blast/BBallBlast.dart';
import 'package:bball_blast/config.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame_forge2d/flame_forge2d.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Ball extends BodyComponent {
  @override
  final BBallBlast game;
  @override
  final Vector2 position;

  //points to draw for trajectory
  late List<Vector2> points;

  //TODO: CHANGE WHEN YOU CHANGE BODY
  late double velocityRatio = 1/28.274333882308138;

  int steps = 180;


  Ball(this.game, this.position, Sprite sprite) : super (
    renderBody: false,

    //start body as static then set as dynamic when it is shot
    bodyDef: BodyDef()
      ..position = position
      ..type = BodyType.static
      ..linearDamping = 0,

    fixtureDefs: [
      FixtureDef(CircleShape()..radius = 6/2)
        ..restitution = 0.3
        ..density = 1
        //..friction = 0.5
    ],

    //add our sprite
    children: [

      SpriteComponent(
        sprite: sprite,
        size: Vector2 (7, 7),
        anchor: Anchor.center,
      )

    ]
  );

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    super.render(canvas);

    //draw projected trajectory with info given by drags 
    if (game.isDragging) {
      //we multiply the input by that number as it's the ratio that converts pixel to velocity
      Vector2 initialVelocity = Vector2(game.dragBehindBall.dx, game.dragBehindBall.dy) * game.linearImpulseStrengthMult * velocityRatio;
      //initialVelocity = _checkVelMax(initialVelocity);
      //print(initialVelocity);
      //get points to draw projected trajectory
      points = trajectoryPoints(initialVelocity, Vector2(game.startPosX, game.startPosY), steps, (1/60)); //60 fps so our dt is 1/60

      Paint paint = Paint()
        ..color = const Color.fromRGBO(244, 67, 54, 1)
        ..strokeWidth = 0.5
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

      for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(points[i].x, points[i].y),
          Offset(points[i + 1].x, points[i + 1].y),
          paint,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  List<Vector2> trajectoryPoints(Vector2 initialVelocity, Vector2 startPos, int steps, double timeStep) {
    List<Vector2> points = [];

    for(int i=0; i<steps+1; i++) {
      //get the timestep for a certain time in place
      double t = i * timeStep;

      //multiply velocity by timestep to get appropriate velocity and grav at ceratain time
      Vector2 stepVel = initialVelocity * t;
      Vector2 stepGrav = Vector2(0.0, 0.5* gravity *(t*t));

      //calculate displacement based on stepVel and stepGrav in relation to starting position
      double xDisplacement = startPos.x + stepVel.x;
      double yDisplacement = startPos.y + stepVel.y + stepGrav.y;

      //form our vectors
      Vector2 pos = Vector2(xDisplacement, yDisplacement);
      points.add(pos);
    }

    return points;
  }

  Vector2 getSuperPosition(){
    return super.position;
  }

}

Thank you for any help someone may provide.

You are hitting the Box2D max velocity, that is why Forge2DGame is zoomed to 10.0 by default, but that zoom level disappears when you use CameraComponent.withFixedResolution.
